# StreamWriter gets "FileNotFound" after writing some data and then just dies

Tags: .net, streamwriter

I have some very simple code to read some records from a DB and then write them out to a CSV file. The writing is done through a StreamWriter. When I run it, it runs fine for a while and then I get a FileNotFoundException.

The file is being written to the same directory as the little executable. When I look there, I can see the file appear, and start to fill up. Then it crashes.  When I look at the SW, it says that it's writing to some other file with a big long name.

Has anyone seen this sort of behavior before?

UPDATE: MS Security Essentials anti-virus only. The fact that it happens at the exact same spot every time suggests the problem is in the code, not external.

Comment: Questions like this need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Share the piece of code where it happens? If you step through the code and keep track of the variable hosting the path to the file you are writing to, do you see when/where the path gets updated to the long invalid path?

Comment: I solved this by adding lots of .Flush. This appears to be a bug in .Net code, it should be saying "OutOfMemory: